# Login not working after php updated

Tags: php

My admin panel of my website is no longer working after the php updated of my hosting

here are the files code that looks very old so i wonder how to edit its code.

1) login.php (it is just simple form)

```
<form method="post" name="login" id="login" action="admin.php">
Username : <input name="loginid" id="loginid" type="text">
Password : <input name="password" id="password" type="password">
</form>
```

2) It send informations to admin.php (here i think there is something been no longer works)

```
<?PHP
session_start();
require_once("../config.php"); // db connection

$loginid = $HTTP_POST_VARS['loginid'];
$password = $HTTP_POST_VARS['password'];

$sql= "select * from settings where admuser='$loginid' and admpass='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("query failed: $sql");

if($line=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

session_register("loginid");
header("Location: home.php ");
exit;

}else{

$msg= "Login Failed";
session_register('msg');
header("Location: login.php ");
exit;

}
?>
```

However it is very simple as my knowledge in php is very small and old but it didn't worked ! so any idea

Note : PHP Version 5.2.17 | register_globals = On (also not working if it Off)

Thanks for help

Comment: have you tried debugging the script to see where it is actually failing/stopping?  Switch the method to GET and use a URL and debug it that way.  Why don't you just use just POST?  HTTP_POST_VARS has been deprecated for a while.  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: Have you tried $_POST instead of $HTTP_POST_VARS ? Any error output ?

Comment: need we remind you of the need to sanitize input? don't discount the $_POST injection hole you have here.

Comment: I use $_REQUEST in most instances, because it combines both $_POST and $_GET vars; therefore it doesn't matter which method you use.  In this case, $_POST is probably the right answer, for security reasons.

Comment: Hmm, has anyone tried logging in with user name and passowrd `' or '1' = '1`? fun times.

Comment: `$_POST` is not any more secure than `$_GET`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These have been deprecated:

```
$loginid = $HTTP_POST_VARS['loginid'];
$password = $HTTP_POST_VARS['password'];
```

should be:

```
$loginid = $_POST['loginid'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

and session_register($msg) should be:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['msg'] = 'Login Failed';
```

Answer (score 4):

Use $_POST instead of $HTTP_POST_VARS.

Answer (score 2):

Not related, but your use of POST variables directly in a SQL string is a prime target for SQL-injection attacks.

Remember little Bobby Tables: http://xkcd.com/327/